# Como puedo escribir una ruta para un srcset en php

Tags: php

Hola queridos compañeros tengo un código simple que me imprime un `string` con un echo pero no me imprime el `string` completo aquí el código

```
<img class="columna" srcset=<?php print addslashes( "../img/{$producto- 
>imagen}500.jpg 300w,../img/{$producto->imagen}500.jpg 
600w,../img/{$producto->imagen}1000.jpg 1000w,../img/{$producto- 
>imagen}1500.jpg 1500w");?> src=<?php echo"../img/{$producto- 
>imagen}1500.jpg"?> alt=<?php echo $producto->descripcion ?>>
        </section><?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: alt=<?php echo $producto->descripcion ?>> si te fijas aqui tienes doble mayor que

Comment: son 2 uno que cierra la imagen y otro que cierra el php de igual manera muchas gracias